# Unable to load android manifest in Visual studio Properties (An error occurred trying to load the page. Index was outside the bounds of the array.)

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, android-manifest

I'm building a mobile application using Xamarin Form.When I tried to open AndroidManifest.xml in Visual Studio 2019 Community by Right Click -> Xamarin.Android Project -> Properties -> Android Manifest , I'm getting following error,

"An error occurred trying to load the page.
Index was outside the bounds of the array."

But the application is working perfectly, just does not show the Android Manifest in properties.

1. I have try recreate the Android Manifest again and replace the old Manifest in Xamarin.Android but it still does not resolve the problem.
2. I have delete bin and obj file of Xamarin.Android but still problem persist.
3. I have create another new Xamarin Form and try to read the AndroidManifest.xml from properties and I can read it. But It just does not show in Xamarin Form my project

4.I have check the Xamarin Log in Visual studio by going too  Help -> Xamarin -> Open Logs . It do show some error log.

Can anyone help me regrading this problem

Xamarin Log

```
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Hooked up SDB tracing adapter
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Initialization finished
Xamarin|Information|0|Xamarin - 16.0.0.513-d16-0+aebc6bdb5
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Hooked up SDB tracing adapter
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Initialization finished
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.XamarinAndroidPackage|Warning|0|Initializing Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.XamarinAndroidPackage
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Hooked up SDB tracing adapter
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Initialization finished
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.XamarinIOSPackage|Warning|0|Initializing Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.XamarinIOSPackage.
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.AndroidVirtualDeviceProvider|Error|0|an error occurred loading avd `5_1`, the system image does not exists
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.AndroidVirtualDeviceProvider|Error|0|an error occurred loading avd `my_device`, the system image does not exists
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.AndroidVirtualDeviceProvider|Error|0|an error occurred loading avd `Nexus_5X_API_21`, the system image does not exists
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.AndroidVirtualDeviceProvider|Error|0|an error occurred loading avd `Pixel_2_Edited_API_28`, the system image does not exists
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.AndroidVirtualDeviceProvider|Error|0|an error occurred loading avd `presentationapp`, the system image does not exists
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.PackageServices|Warning|0|Failed to Restore Nuget packages for project C:\Github\Repositories\VMS\VMS.ResidentMobileApp\VMS.ResidentMobileApp\VMS.ResidentMobileApp.Android\VMS.ResidentMobileApp.Android.csproj.
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.ManifestPropertyPage|Error|0|Index was outside the bounds of the array.
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.ManifestPropertyPage.<GetAndroidResources>d__22.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\717\s\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\PropertyPages\ManifestPropertyPage.cs:line 0
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.ManifestPropertyPage.AddResourcesFolder(IProjectNode project, String kind) in E:\A\_work\717\s\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\PropertyPages\ManifestPropertyPage.cs:line 323
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.ManifestPropertyPage.PopulateIcons() in E:\A\_work\717\s\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\PropertyPages\ManifestPropertyPage.cs:line 317
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.ManifestPropertyPage.RefreshContent() in E:\A\_work\717\s\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\PropertyPages\ManifestPropertyPage.cs:line 160
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.ManifestPropertyPage.<.ctor>b__10_1(ActiveProjectConfigurationChanged ev) in E:\A\_work\717\s\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\PropertyPages\ManifestPropertyPage.cs:line 139
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Devices.XamarinProjectCfgDebugTargetSelection|Error|0|Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.PropertyProviders.AndroidProjectProperties.get_AndroidAppManifest() in E:\A\_work\717\s\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\PropertyProviders\AndroidProjectProperties.cs:line 90
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidDevice.AppliesTo(IProjectNode project) in E:\A\_work\717\s\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Devices\MonoAndroidDevice.cs:line 89
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidDevice.AppliesTo(IProjectNode project, DeviceFilteringOptions options) in E:\A\_work\717\s\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Devices\MonoAndroidDevice.cs:line 100
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Devices.XamarinProjectCfgDebugTargetSelection.FilterDevices(List`1& allDevices, List`1& platformDevices, List`1& unsupportedDevices) in E:\A\_work\717\s\src\Core\VisualStudio.Devices\XamarinProjectCfgDebugTargetSelection.cs:line 226
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.AndroidVirtualDeviceProvider|Error|0|an error occurred loading avd `5_1`, the system image does not exists
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.AndroidVirtualDeviceProvider|Error|0|an error occurred loading avd `my_device`, the system image does not exists
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.AndroidVirtualDeviceProvider|Error|0|an error occurred loading avd `Nexus_5X_API_21`, the system image does not exists
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.AndroidVirtualDeviceProvider|Error|0|an error occurred loading avd `Pixel_2_Edited_API_28`, the system image does not exists
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.AndroidVirtualDeviceProvider|Error|0|an error occurred loading avd `presentationapp`, the system image does not exists
```

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.companyname.VMS.ResidentMobileApp" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <application>
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <application android:label="VMS.ResidentMobileApp.Android"></application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: First of all, please run this project in VS 2017, if you could get the same error? Then, try another computers that intall the VS 2019 to run this project, Could you share a simple demo that re-produce this issue?

Comment: I have run the project in VS2017 still giving same result.
I try another computer with VS2019 and VS2017 still the same. I try to reproduce a small demo with this issue, but other project is working perfectly. I can view Android Manifest in properties for other project. This issue only hapen in my project. I cannot share directly my project. So i will try to reproduce the sample and share it

Comment: Ok, based on your test, we can focus on this issue about your project. Base on my research, this issue is related to some mistakes normally, such as lack of characters, just like "<" ,"/"